# how to find which UITableView row has been clicked ? I have multiple UITableviews on UIScrollView.

Tags: iphone

I have implemented around 10 tables on UIScrollView. I want to know which row of which UITable has been clicked.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add tags to each of the table and then check it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(tableView.tag == 1){
    //do something
    }
    else if(tableView.tag == 2){
    //do something else
    }
    // and so on
}
```

Or else, you could check which instance of tableview is calling the delegate method:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(tableView == self.tableView1){
    //do something
    }
    else if(tableView == self.tableView2){
    //do something else
    }
    // and so on
}
```